# Mail notification when a new user is created in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6. My question is more about syntax. After of the User::create, I wrote this:
RegisterController:

```
Mail::to($user->email)->cc($sponsor1->email)->bcc($sponsor2->email)->send(new NuevoVendedor($user));         return Redirect::to('login');
```

$sponsor1 and $sponsor2, they are just another user, but I'm not receiving any email.

Namespaces imported.

My email service it's working, it works fine when I make a "Forgot your password".

I think, that maybe I'm not having an event to trigger the email sender (?)

How can I see the errors in my Controllers when the're not associated to a get:route view or they're not gettings error to laravel? (In scheduling for example). Is there any way to see the var_dump, dd() or something in a console?

Here is my full registerController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Mail\NuevoVendedor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use App\Notifications\UserRegisteredSuccessfully;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'type' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    { 
        return $user =User::create([
            //general
            'type' => $data['type'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),

            'remember_token'=>$data['_token'],
            'phone_number'=>$data['phone_number'] , 
            'how' =>$data['how'], 
            'state' =>$data['state'], 
            'city' =>$data['city'], 
            'address' =>$data['address'], 
            //usuarios normales 
            'first_name'=> isset($data['first_name']) ? $data['first_name']:null, 
            'last_name'=>isset($data['last_name']) ? $data['last_name']:null , 
            'sponsor'=> isset($data['sponsor']) ? $data['sponsor']:null, 
            //providers
            'commercial_name'=>isset($data['commercial_name']) ? $data['commercial_name']:null,
            'rut'=>isset($data['rut']) ? $data['rut']:null,
            'agcw_sponsor'=>isset($data['agcw_sponsor']) ? $data['agcw_sponsor']:null,

        ]);

        $data["sponsor"] = $sponsorID;

        Log::info($sponsorID);

        $sponsor1=DB::table("users")->select("email","id","sponsor")->where("id","=",$sponsorID)->first();

        $sponsor2id=$sponsor1->sponsor;
        $sponsor2=DB::table("users")->select("email")->where("id","=",$sponsor2id)->first();

        $sponsorEmail=$sponsor1->email;
        $sponsor2Email=$sponsor2query->email;

        Mail::to($data["email"], $sponsorEmail, $sponsor2Email)->send(new NuevoVendedor($user));

        return Redirect::to('login');


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The laravel's documentation sometimes is not enough, so normally I take a look to the [laravel's source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework) to understand how it's implemented.

Looking into the source code of [Mailer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php) and [PendingMail](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Mail/PendingMail.php) class:

You can note that the variable `$cc` is an array, also the functions `to()`, `cc()`, `bcc()` receive an mixed var that later is set to the `$to`, `$cc`, `$bcc` array variables.

Wich means that your method should pass an array of emails instead of a email string.

So if you add brackets wrapping the emails should be fine, like this:

```
Mail::to([$user->email])
      ->cc([$sponsor1->email])
      ->bcc([$sponsor2->email])
      ->send(new NuevoVendedor($user));

return Redirect::to('login');
```

Also I noted that sponsor2 maybe should me with sponsor1 at `cc()` method, so now you can do this:

```
Mail::to([$user->email])
      ->cc([$sponsor1->email, $sponsor2->email])
      ->send(new NuevoVendedor($user));

return Redirect::to('login');
```

Or even you can clear a little bit more:

```
Mail::to([$user->email, $sponsor1->email, $sponsor2->email])
      ->send(new NuevoVendedor($user));

return Redirect::to('login');
```

This Should work, let me know if worked well.

Comment: If still doesn't check you log file in storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: @AmitKumar use the Facede 'Log' to write messages to the log file. Like: `Log::info($message);`.

Don't forget to import the Log class `'use \Log';`

Comment: Also to check the logs just use the command tail to follow the laravel.log: `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Not working, also I can't se anything in laravel logs.